# Blue Screen when i try Install Windows XP X86 in X64 Machine

Tags: windows, windows-xp, 32-bit

I need to install Windows XP X86 in a physical computer. How i don't have a 32bit processor computer, i try to install system in X64 machine.

(i need to test a automation software that available only windows xp X86 :/)

I try to use Ease2Boot and PowerIso Methods, but the both stops in the same place. When the windows begins the installation (before i choose the partition), the blue screen appears and show the same error:

"ERROR: 0X0000007E
ACPI.sys address F73B8D66 base at F73AD000 DATER 41107 27"

I search about this error in internet and didn't find anything that could help.

Anyone have an i idea if it's possible install Windows X86 in X64 Machine?

Ps: Sorry about my bad English

Thanks a lot!

Comment: John's answer is right.  However, if you absolutely must install on a physical machine, you're going to have to find an old one.  Old desktop machines should be readily available at a used computer store or someplace like eBay.  You'll need an XP serial number, too, although you probably already have that if you're attempting an install.

Comment: Get a xp era pc, they are cheap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to install Windows XP X86 in a physical computer. How i don't
> have a 32bit processor computer, i try to install system in X64
> machine.

Any computer built in the last 5 to 7 years will not install XP. It is too old for new computers.

If you wish to run XP then use a virtual machine (VMware Workstation is best for this but there are other apps).

Make sure your physical box supports Hardware Virtualization (maybe needed for the APP; not needed to install 32-bit XP).

Then make an XP virtual machine. I have that running here inside VMware Workstation on a Windows 11 Pro 64-bit host.

Comment: In Vmware i could install, but i really need to install and physical machine. Thanks!

Comment: Look for Vcentre Converter (search for it) and you can use an older version of Converter and you can convert the physical machine to virtual. Otherwise you can still purchase XP on ebay.  Any attempt to run the physical XP machine will have the same errors.